# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor - Get Total Pending Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) with `X` threads to schedule some tasks on my server.

I'm using 2 methods majorly -

1. [schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)
2. [scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

How can I get the total number of pending tasks in the queue waiting to be executed but aren't due to the unavailability of threads? I need this to monitor the lag in the production scenario and tune my `threadPool` according to scale.

for eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    //  PENDING_TASKS -> Should return 2
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new R(),0,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //  PENDING_TASKS -> Should return 3
}

// scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue() -> Doesn't Work
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new R());
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new R(),0,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue().size()); 
    //PRINTS 0. I need 1 because 3rd task should repeat after 1s but is pending since task is 5s long.
}

class R implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " waiting");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " waiting1");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To tell what has yet to execute, track the [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object returned by each of your calls to `schedule` or `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the queue size which should give you an idea for that instant:

```
System.out.println(scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue().size());
```

Note that I don't think your third case with `scheduleAtFixedRate(every second)` should print "1" because the "missed" scheduled at fixed rate items will not build up in the queue if they are running slowly. If one step happens to take 100 seconds, you don't have 99 backed up after it ends, another is kicked off in the next period cycle.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've added example in the question

Comment: Your test crossed over my last edit - only helps you for first case without scheduleAtFixedRate.

Comment: I think "PRINTS 0" is correct after all, `scheduleAtFixedRate` should not be queuing next scheduled task until previous has finished.

Comment: It is correct acc. to the documentation. I'm not contesting its correctness. My requirement is different

Comment: See, You are focusing on why 1 is correct because it will not enqueue. But, my requirement is to track how much it has missed. I can't afford to miss - that's the requirement. I need to track the misses and scale the threadPool accordingly so as to prevent misses

Comment: Understood - though that isn't what the question says. You'd need to track your calls to scheduleAtFixedRate.